# How can I stop a recursive function at a certain level and insert another function there?

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

I have 2 questions: I have a recursive function `M(n)=3*M(n/2)+2*n+1` and  an iterative function `T(n)=n^2`

```cpp
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<bits/stdc++.h> 
    using namespace std; 
  
    int M(int n) 
    { 
   
    if (n == 1) 
        return n; 
    return 3*M(n/2)+2*n+1; 
    
      } 

    int T(int n) 
      {  
    return n^2; 
    
      } 

     int main () 
      { 
  
     cout<< "Cost is "<< M(768)<<"\n";
     getchar(); 
     return 0; 
     }
```

I would like to run 5 levels of recursive `M` function for `n=768`  and then insert `T`  function as below:

M(768)=3*M(384)+O(n)

M(384)=3*M(192)+O(n)

M(192)=3*M(96)+O(n)

M(96)=3*M(48)+O(n)

M(48)=3*M(24)+O(n)

now I would like my program stop here at  `n=24` and insert `$T(24)=24^2$` instead of `M(24)`.

In other words, I would like to combine M(n) and T(n)  functions in that way.

But I could not arrange the recursive code in this way. Can someone help me with this? Do I need to convert M(n) to an iterative function to achieve my goal or can I just fix the recursion? If so, how can I convert to iterative function?

My second question is:

If I run  the code for `M(n)` until the base case `n=1`, I get an error, since for `768=3*256` and 3 is not divisable by 2 exactly. How can I fix this for M(n) only?

Comment: is it always after 5 recursions? Or when the input it `48` ? `24` ?

Comment: "How can I stop a recursive function at certain level" - Count the recursion depth and bail out (or do *whatever*) when it reaches your "max depth", would be one obvious solution..

Comment: @idclev463035818 actually my final goal is to be able to change the 5 value to any other one. But for now 5 would be oki. Number of iterations is the value that I would like to be able to change. Not the 24 or 48. But the iteration number which is 5 there.

Comment: @esra maintain a counter that starts at zero and is incremented every time you recurse. If the counter is `>= 5` bail out.

Comment: ^ is not the power function.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @S.M. thanks for the clerification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get rid of some details so we can concentrate on the essentials. Consider you have this recursive function:

```
int foo(int n) {
    std::cout << "foo(" << n << ")\n";
    // base case
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    // recurse 
    return foo( n-2 );
}
```

and after 5 recursions you want to call some other function

```
int bar(int n){
    std::cout << "bar(" << n << ")\n";
    return 42;
}
```

Then you just need to add a parameter to choose after how many steps the other function should be called, and a counter that counts the recursions:

```
int foofoo(int n, int steps,int counter=1) {
    std::cout << "foofoo(" << n << '\n';
    if (counter == steps) return bar(n);

    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    foofoo(n-2,steps,counter+1);
}
```

Then

```
int main() {
    foofoo(12,5);   
}
```

Prints

```
foofoo(12)
foofoo(10)
foofoo(8)
foofoo(6)
bar(4)
```

PS: `^` is bit-wise XOR, to get the square of `n` write `n*n`.

Comment: Shouldn't foofoo() has 3 argument? am I wrong? Actually,what  I want to get is exactly to insert T(24) into M(24) and get this Result. 
M(768)=3*3*3*3*3*M(24)+O(n)=3*3*3*3*3*T(24)+O(n)=Result.  How can I do this insertion of bar(4), into foofoo(12) instead of foofoo(4)? Thanks by the way for the bitwise or correction and the code.

Comment: @esra the third uses the default.